# TFS 2012 Update 3 Upgrade - Backlog no longer shows bug work item types

Tags: tfs

I'm wondering if anyone on here has recently upgraded to TFS 2012.3 and suffered the same problem?

Previously we where using TFS 2012.2 and had customized the CommonProcessConfig and Categories to display bug work items on the requirements backlog however after the update the backlog page displays the following error.

TF400917: The current configuration is not valid for this feature. This feature cannot be used until you correct the configuration.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I've been through several web blogs, server logs and the exported config files (using witadmin) attempting to find a possible cause and have so far come up blank.

***Catergories XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cat:CATEGORIES xmlns:cat="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/workitemtracking/categories">
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.BugCategory" name="Bug Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Bug" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.CodeReviewRequestCategory" name="Code Review Request Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Code Review Request" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.CodeReviewResponseCategory" name="Code Review Response Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Code Review Response" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.FeedbackRequestCategory" name="Feedback Request Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Feedback Request" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.FeedbackResponseCategory" name="Feedback Response Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Feedback Response" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.HiddenCategory" name="Hidden Types Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Code Review Request" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Code Review Response" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Feedback Request" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Feedback Response" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Shared Steps" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Test Plan" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Test Suite" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Shared Parameter" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" name="Requirement Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Requirement" />
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="Bug" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.SharedStepCategory" name="Shared Step Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Shared Steps" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.TaskCategory" name="Task Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Task" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.TestCaseCategory" name="Test Case Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Test Case" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.TestPlanCategory" name="Test Plan Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Test Plan" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.TestSuiteCategory" name="Test Suite Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Test Suite" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" name="Feature">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Feature" />
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY refname="Microsoft.SharedParameterCategory" name="Shared Parameter Category">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Shared Parameter" />
  </CATEGORY>
</cat:CATEGORIES>
```

***Project Process Configuration***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectProcessConfiguration>
  <BugWorkItems category="Microsoft.BugCategory" pluralName="Bugs" singularName="Bug">
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="Proposed" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
      <State type="Resolved" value="Resolved" />
    </States>
  </BugWorkItems>
  <FeedbackRequestWorkItems category="Microsoft.FeedbackRequestCategory" pluralName="Feedback Requests" singularName="Feedback Request">
    <States>
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
    </States>
  </FeedbackRequestWorkItems>
  <FeedbackResponseWorkItems category="Microsoft.FeedbackResponseCategory" pluralName="Feedback Responses" singularName="Feedback Response">
    <States>
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
    </States>
  </FeedbackResponseWorkItems>
  <PortfolioBacklogs>
    <PortfolioBacklog category="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" pluralName="Features" singularName="Feature">
      <AddPanel>
        <Fields>
          <Field refname="System.Title" />
        </Fields>
      </AddPanel>
      <Columns>
        <Column width="100" refname="System.WorkItemType" />
        <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
        <Column width="100" refname="System.State" />
        <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue" />
        <Column width="200" refname="System.Tags" />
      </Columns>
      <States>
        <State type="Proposed" value="Proposed" />
        <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
        <State type="InProgress" value="Resolved" />
        <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
      </States>
    </PortfolioBacklog>
  </PortfolioBacklogs>
  <RequirementBacklog category="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" parent="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" pluralName="Requirements" singularName="Requirement">
    <AddPanel>
      <Fields>
        <Field refname="System.Title" />
        <Field refname="Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.RequirementType" />
      </Fields>
    </AddPanel>
    <Columns>
      <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
      <Column width="100" refname="System.State" />
      <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Size" />
      <Column width="150" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.RequirementType" />
      <Column width="200" refname="System.IterationPath" />
      <Column width="200" refname="System.Tags" />
    </Columns>
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="Proposed" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Resolved" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
    </States>
  </RequirementBacklog>
  <TaskBacklog category="Microsoft.TaskCategory" parent="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" pluralName="Tasks" singularName="Task">
    <AddPanel>
      <Fields>
        <Field refname="System.Title" />
      </Fields>
    </AddPanel>
    <Columns>
      <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Size" />
      <Column width="400" refname="System.Title" />
      <Column width="100" refname="System.State" />
      <Column width="100" refname="System.AssignedTo" />
      <Column width="50" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" />
    </Columns>
    <States>
      <State type="Proposed" value="Proposed" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Resolved" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
    </States>
  </TaskBacklog>
  <TypeFields>
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Discipline" type="Activity" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank" type="Order" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationLaunchInstructions" type="ApplicationLaunchInstructions" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationStartInformation" type="ApplicationStartInformation" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Feedback.ApplicationType" type="ApplicationType">
      <TypeFieldValues>
        <TypeFieldValue type="ClientApp" value="Client application" />
        <TypeFieldValue type="RemoteMachine" value="Remote machine" />
        <TypeFieldValue type="WebApp" value="Web application" />
      </TypeFieldValues>
    </TypeField>
    <TypeField format="{0} h" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" type="RemainingWork" />
    <TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Size" type="Effort" />
    <TypeField refname="System.AreaPath" type="Team" />
  </TypeFields>
  <Weekends>
    <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
    <DayOfWeek>Saturday</DayOfWeek>
  </Weekends>
  <WorkItemColors>
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFCC293D" secondary="FFFAEAE5" name="Bug" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Change Request" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Code Review Request" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Code Review Response" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FF773B93" secondary="FFEEE2F2" name="Feature" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Feedback Request" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Feedback Response" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Issue" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FF009CCC" secondary="FFD6ECF2" name="Requirement" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Review" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Risk" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Shared Steps" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFF2CB1D" secondary="FFF6F5D2" name="Task" />
    <WorkItemColor primary="FFFF9D00" secondary="FFFCEECF" name="Test Case" />
  </WorkItemColors>
</ProjectProcessConfiguration>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the answer to why I was getting a failure with the new system. Basically the Requirement Backlog element in the Project Process Configuration file defined a 'RequirementType' in the Panels section as shown below:

```
 <RequirementBacklog category="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" parent="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" pluralName="Requirements" singularName="Requirement">
    <AddPanel>
      <Fields>
        <Field refname="System.Title" />
        <Field refname="Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.RequirementType" />
      </Fields>
    </AddPanel>
```

This meant that when the Bug WIT was added to the requirement in the categories XML it expected the field 'Requirement Type' to exist on the bug WIT. In order to fix this I had two possibilities:

1) Add the 'Requirement Type' to the bug WIT
2) Remove the 'Requirement Type' from the panel.

I choose option 2 as option 1 wouldn't have made much sense from a users point of view. This resulted in the Requirement Backlog looking like this:

```
<RequirementBacklog category="Microsoft.RequirementCategory" parent="Microsoft.FeatureCategory" pluralName="Requirements" singularName="Requirement">
        <AddPanel>
          <Fields>
            <Field refname="System.Title" />
          </Fields>
        </AddPanel>
```

Use witadmin to re-import the process configuration and the problem is solved and bugs are once again viewable on the requirement backlog page. :)